# Installing LAMP

Tags: software-installation, lamp

I’m new to Linux and Ubuntu. I’m running Ubuntu 13.10 on a mac OS 10.9 machine using Oracle’s VBBox VM software. How do I set up the LAMP suite of software—Linux, Apache, MySQL, and PHP? Can you direct me to any online documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Try running `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` in a terminal and answering yes when it asks if you want to continue.

Answer (score 2):

Open your terminal and install tasksel with

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

and type as

```
sudo tasksel
```

There select Lamp server with space bar and then select ok as I have show in the image that will install lamp server in your Ubuntu automatically.

[image]