# I have just installed LAMP server through tasksel. Can I use it in any graphical way?

Tags: gui, lamp

I have just installed LAMP server, as [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/378664/338446) suggested. Tasksel shows it is installed, but I see no option to use it, except for the terminal. As a user new to Linux, I would prefer something GUI-based, more similar to WAMP or XAMPP on Windows. Can I add some GUI easily, or do I have to uninstall it and find some version different from that offered by tasksel?

I faced some problems while installing XAMPP on Ubuntu, so I don't want "install XAMPP" answers unless there's really no other option.

Comment: "so I don't want "install XAMPP" answers " since most of us do not consider that a very well thought out product you probably never will see that as an answer ;)

Comment: Anything else needed besides these 3? :)

Comment: There is also phpmyadmin

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **Apache**

- [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) ([Installation guide](http://www.webmin.com/deb.html))

> Webmin is a web-based interface for system administration for Unix. Using any modern web browser, you can setup user accounts, Apache, DNS, file sharing and much more. Webmin removes the need to manually edit Unix configuration files like /etc/passwd, and lets you manage a system from the console or remotely. See the [standard modules page](http://www.webmin.com/standard.html) for a list of all the functions built into Webmin, or check out the [screenshots](http://www.webmin.com/demo.html).

[image]

There is also [apacheConf](http://www.apache-gui.com/apache-linux.html).

> ApacheConf is the progam that can configure the remote Apache servers on Linux machines. It will help you to tune the main Apache configuration httpd.conf file on Linux. ApacheConf presents all the information in the httpd.conf file in a structured view. All of the server's directives are grouped by category (Global parameters, Main server's parameters, Directories, Virtual hosts, etc) and all these groups are represented as a tree. In this way, you can see the entire structure of the server on Linux computer at a glance and you can easily manage all of the server's directives, as well as the directories and virtual hosts.

[image]

It has some cave-ats: it implements its own structure and ignores any Ubuntu specific configuration and you are bound to the GUI (if it is not implemented into the GUI...)

---

> **MySQL**

For MySQL I would suggest [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). [There is a special APT repo for MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/). From the link:

> The MySQL APT repository provides a simple and convenient way to
>   install and update MySQL products with the latest software packages
>   using Apt.
>
> The APT repository supports the following Linux Distros:
>
> ```
> Debian - 7
> Ubuntu - 12.04 LTS
> Ubuntu - 14.04 LTS
> Ubuntu - 14.10
> ```
>
> MySQL APT repository includes the latest packages:
>
> ```
> MySQL 5.6 (GA)
> MySQL 5.7 (Development Release)
> MySQL Workbench 6.2 (GA) - Ubuntu Only
> MySQL Connector / Python
> ```

---

> **PHP**

There probably is not a lot for PHP besides the "[phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)" function you can add to a webpage and show anything loaded. Example from the link:

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

// Show just the module information.
// phpinfo(8) yields identical results.
phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);

?>
```

Save it in your root as "phpinfo.php" and point your browser to it (ie. http://localhost/phpinfo.php)